# Images in Grails stylesheets dont work

Tags: grails

I'm using Grails 2.0 and specified my css stylesheets and javascript files in the application resources file so that I can use syntax like `<r:require modules="common"/>`

In my resource file I have specified a css file which in turn uses in image background...

```
jrac {
   dependsOn 'jquery-dev'
   resource url: '/js/misc/jrac.js'
   resource url: '/css/misc/jrac.css', bundle:'bundle_style'
}
```

jrac.css 
...

```
.jrac_loading {
    background-image: url('../../images/misc/loading.gif');
}
```

The issue is that when I run this in the browser, the parsed file changes the url to:

```
background-image: url('resource:/images/misc/loading.gif');
```

So the image doesn't work, does anyone have any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was with the lesscss plugin. If you use this plugin you must set your less output to a separate bundle, otherwise url rewriting doesn't seem to play well.